# How to check replicated domain controllers for active during connection

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

We have a set of replicated domain controllers, but not a load balancer, so when making connections we have to specify a controller. Even if we only input the domain the script makes one connection and if it fails, it fails, and doesn't loop back to check the others.

Is there a way to check for an active connection first between the various controllers, then use the first one it connects to in the connection string?

Right now I'm looking at a script that I didn't write and I am green to powershell so I don't have much of a clue right now, but this is the string:

```
foreach($ou in $OUS) {
Write-Output "Exporting $ou to CSV"
$out += Get-ADUser -Server "blank.io" -searchbase $ou -Properties * -Filter { mail -like "*blank.io" } |
Select-Object @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.givenName}},

---- Code goes on, this is just the pertinent stuff
```

Thanks

Comment: The AD cmdlets automatically select a domain controller in the current site.

Comment: Perhaps something like `Get-ADDomainController -Discover -NextClosestSite -ForceDiscover` helps.

Comment: Worth noting that `Get-ADDomainController -Discover` in turn results in a call to `netapi32.dll`, at which point the `netlogon` service on the machine will go through site-aware DC discovery and perform a so-called "LDAP Ping" before returning a DC - so you don't need to worry about any of that :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you just don't specify a `-Server` argument? If the concern is staleness of replicated data, and network connectivity between the DCs are a non-issue, then the obvious solution is to lower the inter-site replication delay in AD and review the site links